# Postgres : psql: FATAL: database "uniprojectv20" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

I am new to postgresql , I Have install postgres in my computer and create database called `uniprojectv20` and also create user called `uniserved_db` and grant all the access to database `uniprojectv20`. I am fetching following problem:

```
rahul@HP-EliteBook ~ $ psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.3

postgres=# \l
                                     List of databases
     Name      |    Owner     | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |       Access privileges       
---------------+--------------+----------+---------+-------+-------------------------------
 postgres      | postgres     | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | 
 rahul         | postgres     | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | 
 template0     | postgres     | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =c/postgres                  +
               |              |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1     | postgres     | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =c/postgres                  +
               |              |          |         |       | postgres=CTc/postgres
 uniprojectv20 | uniserved_db | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN | =Tc/uniserved_db             +
               |              |          |         |       | uniserved_db=CTc/uniserved_db
(5 rows)

postgres=# \q
postgres@HP-EliteBook ~ $ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U uniserved_db -W uniprojectv20
Password for user uniserved_db: 
**psql: FATAL:  database "uniprojectv20" does not exist**
postgres@HP-EliteBook ~ $ psql uniprojectv20
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

uniprojectv20=#
```

Also If I tried to connect from another user instead of postgres I am facing same problem .

```
rahul@HP-EliteBook ~ $ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U uniserved_db -W uniprojectv20
Password for user uniserved_db: 
psql: FATAL:  database "uniprojectv20" does not exist
```

Comment: please run `show port;` in `psql`

Comment: `postgres=# show port;
 port 
------
 5433
(1 row)`

Comment: so then try connecting `psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U uniserved_db -W uniprojectv20`?..

Comment: OMG, Thanks but why default port i.e., `5432` got changes to `5433`?

Comment: Oh Thanks !!, Accepted

Comment: because you created another cluster - so it took a free port. try `pg_lsclusters`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have several postgres clusters on same machine. So you have `uniprojectv20` database in one, and not in other.

try `psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U uniserved_db -W uniprojectv20` for cluster on port 5433.

To list all clusters, try running `pg_lsclusters` it should show data dirs, ports and versions

Comment: Thank you for this! Was going nuts trying to connect to my database on port 5432 in DBeaver but `pg_lsclusters` showed the cluster was on port 5433